# Is it okay to have duplicate IDs in multiple contact forms if needed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, contacts

Can anyone help with this? I really need to get it sorted. Please read fully and look at the site to see what i mean specifically...

I have a simple contact form for each item (10 items+) on a, for all intents and purposes, an item gallery.

But when I run through a validator it says i have duplicate IDs. The forms all work as intended but I'm guessing this will become a problem at some point

I have a single "html_form_send.php" which all my forms point to is there a way to get round the duplicate IDs?

Can i class the ID's instead? If so do i need to amend the "html_form_send.php" and "....css" files to accommodate this? If so in what way?

If you need to page to look at its http://www.flowright.net/fullrange

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
    <table>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="first_name">Full name *</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input  type="text" id="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="last_name">Company *</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input  type="text" id="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input  type="text" id="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>      
            <td>
                <label for="telephone">Telephone Number *</label>
            </td>        
            <td>
                <input  type="text" id="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="comments">Message / Query *</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea id="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="40" rows="6">**REF SITRANS MAG 1100**</textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: No, but as stated above this is the form that is repeated in the page link above (over 20 times). So its these IDs that are duplicated throughout the page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't see duplicate id's in the code you posted, but you did mention you ran it through some sort of validator. You should really specify what validator you are using and what it's response is. Also, your label tag says "Full Name" but your id is for first_name, and your label for "Company" has an id for last_name. You should also be declaring the correct types for your inputs (type="email", type="tel")

I am assuming you are using one of the id's in your code somewhere else in the remainder of your body, but either way, it is okay to use class instead of id. It really comes down to what you are trying to do. The purpose of id and class is mostly for css specificity. When using it with javascript, using css selectors is just one of many ways to select DOM elements (but it is probably the easiest).

Comment: I have over 20 of these forms (full code block above x20) on the same page (link above) So its these specific ids that are duplicated throughout the page. The mis name between ids is fine.

The text tips just says what i want them to put in the box